# docker-compose run returns /bin/ls cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker

I have just started learning Docker, and run into this issue which don't know how to go abound.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:7.0.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
COPY hermes-entry /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/hermes-entry
COPY entry.d /entry.d
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install gulp
RUN gulp
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  hermes:
    build: .
    container_name: hermes
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
   entrypoint: /bin/bash
   links:
     - postgres
   depends_on:
     - postgres
   tty: true
postgres:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  volumes:  
    - ~/.docker-volumes/hermes/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  ports:
  - "2345:5432"
```

After starting the containers up with:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

I tried running a simple bash cmd:

```sh
docker-compose run hermes ls
```

And I got this error:

```
/bin/ls cannot execute binary file
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 18):

The `entrypoint` to your container is `bash`.  By default bash expects a shell script as its first argument, but `/bin/ls` is a binary, as the error says.  If you want to run `/bin/ls` you need to use `-c /bin/ls` as your command.  `-c` tells bash that the rest of the arguments are a command line rather than the path of a script, and the command line happens to be a request to run `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score -2):

You can't run Gulp and Node at the same time in one container. Containers should always have one process each.

If you just want node to serve files, remove your entrypoint from the hermes service.

You can add another service to run gulp, if you are having it run tests, you'd have to map the same volume and add a command: ["gulp"]

And you'd need to remove RUN gulp from your dockerfile (unless you are using it to build your node files)

then run docker-compose up